# what does $(1:D=) mean?

Tags: shell, jam

I'm reading Jamrule file of some project to understand how it builds.
But there is some that I can't understand.
Such like `$(1:D=) or $(1:S=$(sample)) or $(1:G=$(sample))`
what does it mean?

I searched colon and equal meaning in a shell script but I couldn't find when the alphabet is in between them.

ex) `local _s = $(1:D=) ;`

Comment: I do know the shell command `_s=${1:-D=}`, (without spaces and curly brackets and an extra char before the `D`, did you paste the command correctly ?

Comment: Maybe it's an emoticon joke with a tongue hanging out and a beard - tilt your head so your left ear is on your left shoulder to see it.

Comment: It's definitely not shell syntax. You'd have to consult the Jam documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(1)` expands the first argument of a rule. `$(1:D=foo)` applies a modifier that replaces the directory portion of the expanded elements (dirname, if you think in shell terms) with the string `foo`. The special case `$(1:D=)` removes the directory portion. The modifier `S` refers to the suffix (aka extension) of the file name, `G` to the "grist" of a jam target name.

Please refer to the [Variable Expansion section](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/view/guest/perforce_software/jam/src/Jam.html#varexp) of the Perforce Jam documentation for a complete list. I can recommend reading the complete Jam documentation to understand the specific concepts (like grist).